# Portal Site on WSS

Tags: wss-3.0

I have tow questions..

Could I create a complete portal for Internet with WSS 3.0 or MOSS is nessesary for that?

I wanted to know if it is possible to install WSS 3.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2003 is the only possibility for this version of Sharepoint.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are referring to CMS functions, you are going to face some real limitations.  The publishing features are not available.  In addition, you can do some basic content approval, but the regular workflows are not available.  I wouldn't consider the Content Editor Web Part to be real CMS.  Not having the layout pages would make this incredibly difficult to even roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can create portals for the internet with WSS 3.0 without moss.  But I'm not really sure of your definition of portal or what features and functionality you are expecting.  At my work, we have some custom templates based on teamsites that are used at "portals" accessible over the internet.

Really, moss is just microsoft's add on to WSS.  So who's to say you can't write your own on top of wss without using moss.

Yes, you can run wss 3.0 on 2008 r2.  I think you'll need to slipstream SP2 into your install before you run it.  See here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261890(office.12).aspx

Comment: I reffer to create CMS with WSS, I say end users modifing – Edu 29 secs ago content in the web site .

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of companies that use WSS instead of the full MOSS (Std or Ent) for a variety of reasons.  There is a big difference in features, but not all features are needed in all situations.

From my perspective I typically think about WSS working fine with very small companies, work groups or organizations that want lots of loosely connected sites.

Having MOSS adds a layer to help manage the system and content across those sites.  The services in the Shared Service Provider for example offers shared User Profiles that can be managed centrally and shared across all site collections.  Search is much more flexible, and then there are the other advanced Enterprise features.

Comment: I reffer to create CMS with WSS, I say end users modifing

Comment: content in the web site